# Uploading chatter profile photo from Site

Tags: apex, chatter

I am trying to upload Chatter profile photo from site. I have gone through the URL below, but still I am not getting the idea of how to achieve this. Please provide some code snippet or suggestions how to achieve this.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterUsers_static_methods.htm

```
final PageReference theUrll = new PageReference(SERVER_URL+'services/data/v30.0/connect/communities/0DB110000004CB‌​  EGA2/chatter/users/me/photo'); 
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
req.setMethod('POST');   
req.setEndpoint(theUrll.getUrl());
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' +    UserInfo.getSessionId()); 
req.setHeader('cropSize', '120'); 
req.setHeader('cropX', '0');
req.setHeader('cropY', '0'); 
 req.setHeader('fileId', fileId); 
Http http = new Http(); HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code that you've tried so far?

Comment: final PageReference theUrll = new PageReference(SERVER_URL+'services/data/v30.0/connect/communities/0DB110000004CBEGA2/chatter/users/me/photo'); HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();    req.setMethod('POST');
           req.setEndpoint(theUrll.getUrl());
           req.setHeader('Authorization', '120');
           req.setHeader('cropSize', 'OAuth ' +  UserInfo.getSessionId());
           req.setHeader('cropX', '0');
           req.setHeader('cropY', '0');
           req.setHeader('fileId', fileId); 
           Http http = new Http();
           HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

Comment: You've mixed up the headers in your http request, `Authorization` should have `oAuth SessionID`, and `cropSize` should be `120`.

Comment: But its throwing some exception [{"message":"The Chatter Connect API is not enabled for this organization or user type.","errorCode":"API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG"}].The way I am trying may be wrong.So I want to use connect API by following the above URL.If you can provide some code how to use connect API static method to upload an image in binary format , it will be really helpfull.

Comment: Sorry that was a type mistake.

Comment: Is Chatter enabled for your org?Is your user API user

Comment: yes its enabled.I have checked it .I am using the same for other chatter functionality.Its working properly.

Comment: Double check that your user profile has API enabled and chatter related permissions too.

Comment: Yes I checked it , API is enabled and chatter related permissions also.   Can you please suggest me how to use Connect API's setPhoto(String, String, ConnectApi.BinaryInput)  method .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check the below code.It may help you.
   *ConnectApi.BinaryInput fileUpload = new ConnectApi.BinaryInput(fileAsBlob, 'image/jpg', 'profileImage');

   ConnectApi.Photo photoProfile = ConnectApi.ChatterUsers.setPhoto(communityId,userId,fileUpload);*